# Advice on converting a D&D adventure to Savage Worlds Fantasy

Tags: savage-worlds, savage-worlds-fantasy, conversion

Are there any useful rules, tips or suggestions for converting a D&D adventure to Savage Worlds with the Fantasy Companion?

See also: [Zadmar advise](http://www.peginc.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=426817#426817)

Also my answer below.

Comment: rather than adding that link as part of the question, wouldn't it be cleaner and more in working with the way the site works to answer your own question using information from the link?

Comment: Please be my guess to do so. A few hours ago there was an answer which I commented on with this. It seams to have been deleted by the owner.

Comment: It doesn't really make sense in the question.

Comment: I'm closing this as too broad, as I believe it doesn't meet our current quality standards. "Are there any tips" etc isn't a solveable problem, so this question's a discussion starter that our [help/dont-ask] advises against. However, we could potentially reformulate this as "How do I do this?" instead of "Are there any rules/tips/suggestions for doing this?" if that would be appropriate.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because the game systems are so different, I would regard it more as reimagining rather than conversion. Monsters vary widely in effectiveness from their D&D counterparts. You can roughly equate levels to D&D levels, but really that's less useful than you'd think.

Conversion Process as I'd Do It:

1. Steal the plot and locations and NPC personalities.
2. Sub in monsters appropriate to the adventure and CR - you probably can't use a werewolf for a werewolf or the like, as monsters are generally a "bigger deal" in Savage Worlds.
3. Build relevant NPCs. Really you just need to preserve the feel and whether they are higher level/lower level/what than the PCs.  Beware that levels aren't as important in SW - in D&D a three level differential is a big deal, in SW maybe not.

Answer (score -2):

Further:

I have been running Pathfinder adventures converted using the following tools.

[SavageVancianMagic](http://www.godwars2.org/SavageWorlds/SavageVancianMagic.pdf), [Monster Converter](http://www.godwars2.org/SavageWorlds/monster.html), [Skills and DC to TN](http://www.godwars2.org/SavageWorlds/SWotBS_GM.pdf)